# Google App Engine ndb.IN query limits

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python

I was trying to find out the maximum count of list items that can be provided in ndb.IN query for equality comparison, but documentation does not state the same anywhere.

Here's What I am trying to implement?
I have a list of users, which have some relation to the actual user. I also have a Feed items, which I want to be sorted in the terms of relation between the user and the Feed creator. 
To do the same, I thought of 3 different types of queries:
  1. Feeds which belong to users with direct relations
  2. Feeds which belong to users with indirect relations
  3. Feeds which belong to users with no relations.

I want to know if there's a better approach to do the same.

Comment: I seem to recall an old limit but I cannot find reference to it in the docs or in the sdk. An IN query is translated to a bunch of ndb.OR using the equality filters in the background anyway so it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston: do you mean that only 30 items are supported in ndb.IN query?